# Stub / override a controller method in a cucumber test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I am trying to simulate an external API failure in a cucumber test.  The controller action that calls the external API does so via a controller method called `post_to_connect`.  That service runs locally during testing and so the happy path tests just work.  However, my controller action looks like this:

```
def create_connection_test

  post_to_connect # posts to external API
  redirect_to '/success'

rescue => e
  @error = e.to_s
  redirect_to '/connection-test/new'
end
```

And I need to force `post_to_connect` to raise an error so I can write my cucumber test for the sad path.  Here's what I've tried:

Inside the feature file:

```
  Scenario: API failure is handled gracefully
    Given I am on the LDAP Connect stage
    And The connect API will fail
    And I click "Connect"
    Then I see the correct error message
```

Inside the step definition:

```
Then(/^The connect API will fail$/) do
  allow_any_instance_of(LdapController).to receive(:post_to_connect)
    .and_raise("some error")
end
```

This does *not* result in the controller method `post_to_connect` throwing an error?  What am I doing wrong and how can I accomplish overriding `post_to_connect` correctly?

Comment: Because the request is executed from a different process than your cucumber test, they don't share the same memory. You cannot stub it like in a unit test. You have to find another way to fail your API call.

Comment: In Java, we can use MockServer or WireMock to mock (stub actually) external services. Are there similar tools for Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

As Alexis said - this is not possible because your cucumber scenarios are run in one process, and through interacting via the browser - the app itself is in a separate realm.

What I would do is I would have a step called something like this:

`And XYZ api endpoint is off`

And in this step, you do whatever you have to do to disable the endpoint. For example, you can `ps aux | grep ...` to find a process id and kill it. (remember to restart it afterward, or add `And XYZ endpoint is on` to the "happy" scenarios).

Or send a request to the mock-service running locally to not process the next request.

The idea is that the locally running service is under your control (either just by running on the same machine - you can kill it, or by implementing some other mechanism that will allow you to send a signal so it behaves as if it was faulty)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record a failed response for the api call. Then you won't have to worry about making the endpoint fail each time you run the cuke.